# z-index in overlapping divs

Tags: html, z-index

I have the following situation, not sure how z-index is supposed to work in this case:

```
<div style="z-index:0">
My Content
    <div style="z-index:-100">
       My Invisible Content
            <div style="z-index:100">
               My Visisble handle
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like "My Visible Handle"... well, to be visible. Currently it isn't.
How can I get it shown?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Because the div's are nested, the z-index values don't relate to each other.

Try a very high z-index value, it might work in some browsers and not others though so it's best having the div's you want to relate to one another in the same context (nesting level)

Comment: so you mean that my solution is to take the  "My Visisble handle" div ou to the second level instead of second? I am afraid this is not possible for me :(

Comment: or use a very high index like 9000. as the div's are nested they may scale. as Shikiryu says try absolutely positioning them.

Answer (score 1):

If you **really** need to stay with that html, you could/should :

- position your divs (invisible -> relative, visible -> absolute).
- put the *visible* one over the *invisible* (visibile -> top:0; left:0;)
- add a background to the *visible* one if you don't want to see what's behind it ;)
- add a fixed width & height for both of them (in case the content of the *invisible* one is wider)

Result here : http://www.jsfiddle.net/H7BwV/